# How to reflect annotations in Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-2.10

I am trying to discover if a trait's value has an annotation associated to it. After reviewing the Scala 2.10-M7 reflection API I thought that the *getAnnotations* method (located in *Symbol*) could be a great candidate, but it is returning an empty list, as shown in the following REPL session:

```
scala> class W extends scala.annotation.Annotation
defined class W

scala> trait A { @W val a: Int }
defined trait A

scala> typeOf[A].members.last
res0: $r.intp.global.Symbol = value a

scala> res0.getAnnotations
res1: List[$r.intp.global.AnnotationInfo] = List()
```

Are those "annotations" the same annotations I am trying to deal with? How can I know if *a* is annotated with *W*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6325

update. Actually it's not a bug, but a combination of non-obvious ways of how annotations work in Scala. There is a way to make abstract annotated vals in traits work as desired. Take a look at the discussion at the aforementioned links for more details.

Comment: I thought Scala annotations were not preserved at run time?

Comment: They aren't supposed to be visible by Java reflection, but they should be stored in Scala pickles. What I overlooked though is that you need to subclass either `StaticAnnotation` or `ClassfileAnnotation` for that to work. Subclassing just `Annotation` won't cut it, at least according to Scaladoc.

Comment: In a few days, when I have time, I'll clarify the intended behavior, apply fixes if necessary and will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The bug still stands, because even if W extends StaticAnnotation, getAnnotations returns Nil. Changing a to def instead of val fixes the problem.